# SSIS derived column - replace operation on DT_TEXT Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm sure there is an obvious mistake here, but I've tried a number of variations and can't quite find the correct combination!

All I'm trying to do is to replace double quotes in a DT_TEXT string with an apostrophe. I've cast the search/replace as DT_TEXT. This is my latest attempt ...

```
replace( [Summary_N],(DT_TEXT,1252)"\"",(DT_TEXT,1252)"'")
```

However, SSIS throws the error

> *The function "REPLACE" does not support the data type "DT_TEXT" for
>   parameter number 1. The type of parameter could not be implicitly cast
>   into a compatible type for the function. To perform this operation,
>   the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.*

I have found a solution via SQL using this assortment of CASTS, but would be very interested in seeing how this might be achieved as a derived column!

```
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(d.summary AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '"','''') AS NTEXT) as [Summary]
```

Comment: Can you cast the column as DT_WSTR instead?

Comment: See if this helps:   https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic713485-148-1.aspx

Comment: @TabAlleman. Thanks for the link. I had considered using a script, but wanted to see if there were other derived column solutions out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE will not support DT_Text data type, replace DT_Text with DT_STR. Change your command to:
replace( [Summary_N],(DT_STR,1,1252)"\"",(DT_STR,1,1252)"'")

This should work. Hope it helps.